# Run Lua commands in Awesome window manager

Tags: ubuntu, awesome, lua

I need to have network widget in my `Awesome` manager. When I placed in very bottom of `rc.lua` line

```
awful.util.spawn("nm-applet")
```

my `Awesome` was not starting until I have removed it. What is wrong with it?

Is it possible run `Lua` commands just in terminal?

Answer (score 1):

That command should work fine.

Did you see any errors?

Try the follwing in a terminal and check for a response:

```
echo "return awful.util.spawn('nm-applet')" | awesome-client
```

You could also try using the full path: `/usr/bin/nm-applet`